# data transformation using the mutate function in R

Tags: r, function, datatable, tidyverse

I installed the `nycflights13` package and the `tidyverse` package

Here is the first 6 rows of the flight data set

```
    head(flights)
# A tibble: 6 x 19
   year month   day dep_time sched_dep_time dep_delay arr_time sched_arr_time arr_delay carrier flight tailnum origin
  <int> <int> <int>    <int>          <int>     <dbl>    <int>          <int>     <dbl> <chr>    <int> <chr>   <chr> 
1  2013     1     1      517            515         2      830            819        11 UA        1545 N14228  EWR   
2  2013     1     1      533            529         4      850            830        20 UA        1714 N24211  LGA   
3  2013     1     1      542            540         2      923            850        33 AA        1141 N619AA  JFK   
4  2013     1     1      544            545        -1     1004           1022       -18 B6         725 N804JB  JFK   
5  2013     1     1      554            600        -6      812            837       -25 DL         461 N668DN  LGA   
6  2013     1     1      554            558        -4      740            728        12 UA        1696 N39463  EWR   
with 19 variables: year <int>, month <int>, day <int>, dep_time <int>, sched_dep_time <int>, dep_delay <dbl>,
arr_time <int>, sched_arr_time <int>, arr_delay <dbl>, carrier <chr>, flight <int>, tailnum <chr>, origin <chr>,
dest <chr>, air_time <dbl>, distance <dbl>, hour <dbl>, minute <dbl>, time_hour <dttm>
```

I am trying to do two things.

- 1: add a new column at the end of this data set using the `mutate()`
- 2: In this new column I want to compute the total proportion of the delay for each destination. Meaning I will have to calculate the total minutes of `arr_delay`

Here is the code I am running. I used the select function to create my data table. I created the new column using the mutate function but I am having trouble writing a line of code to calculate the proportion for each row or destination  (there are 336,776 rows)

```
new.table<-select(flights, dest, month, day, dep_time, carrier, flight, arr_delay)
mutate(new.table, arr_delay_prop=sum(arr_delay)/(1:336776))
```

**I understand I need to use the sum function to get the total sum of the arrival delay but I am not sure how to take a proportion for each row against the total arr_delay.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this?

```
mutate(new.table, arr_delay_prop=arr_delay/sum(arr_delay, na.rm = T))

# A tibble: 336,776 x 8
   dest  month   day dep_time carrier flight arr_delay arr_delay_prop
   <chr> <int> <int>    <int> <chr>    <int>     <dbl>          <dbl>
 1 IAH       1     1      517 UA        1545        11     0.00000487
 2 IAH       1     1      533 UA        1714        20     0.00000886
 3 MIA       1     1      542 AA        1141        33     0.0000146 
 4 BQN       1     1      544 B6         725       -18    -0.00000797
 5 ATL       1     1      554 DL         461       -25    -0.0000111 
 6 ORD       1     1      554 UA        1696        12     0.00000532
 7 FLL       1     1      555 B6         507        19     0.00000842
 8 IAD       1     1      557 EV        5708       -14    -0.00000620
 9 MCO       1     1      557 B6          79        -8    -0.00000354
10 ORD       1     1      558 AA         301         8     0.00000354
# ... with 336,766 more rows
```

Comment: Yes thank you! I see the mistake I made and also needed to include to the na.rm = T to not include missing values.